# How to deal with an 64 digit input for a Karatsuba algorithm implementation in java

Tags: java, algorithm, multiplication, karatsuba

This is my implementation and what i need for it is to calculate the multiplication of two 64 digit number.  So type Long is not enough (even tho the one with parameter type of long worked just fine).
However when running with String, this popped up

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:67)
at java.base/java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:721)
at java.base/java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:836)
at IntegerMultipl.karatsuba(IntegerMultipl.java:60)
at IntegerMultipl.karatsuba(IntegerMultipl.java:51)
at IntegerMultipl.karatsuba(IntegerMultipl.java:54)
at IntegerMultipl.main(IntegerMultipl.java:17)
```

Any help would be appreciated. This is my implementation of it.

```java
public class IntegerMultipl {
    
    // 24 * 19 = 456
    /**
     *  a = 2 b = 4 
     *  c = 1 d = 9 
     * ac = 2 bd = 36
     * (a+b)(c+d) -ac -bd = 6 * 9 - 2 - 36 = 22
     * ac * (10 ^2 ) + bd + (22)* 10 
     * = 200 + 36 +220 
     */

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long res = karatsuba(19,22);
        System.out.println(res);
        String result = karatsuba("19", "22");
        System.out.println(result);
        
        
    }
    /** only works when the in put is incide the range of long */
    public static long karatsuba(long x, long y){
        long n = Long.toString(x).length();
        long half = n / 2 ;
        if( x / 10 >= 1 ){
            long a = x / (long)Math.pow(10, half);
            long b = x % (long)Math.pow(10, half);
            long c = y / (long)Math.pow(10, half);
            long d =  y % (long)Math.pow(10, half);
            long fst = karatsuba(a, c);
            long lst = karatsuba(b, d);
            long trick = karatsuba(a+b, c+d) - fst - lst;
            return (long)Math.pow(10, n)* fst + lst + (long)Math.pow(10, half) * trick;
        }
        else{
                return x*y;
        }

    }
    public static String karatsuba(String x, String y){
        int n = x.length();
        int m = y.length();
        int half = n / 2 ;
        if( n > 1 ){
            String a = x.substring(0, half);
            String b = x.substring(half);
            String c = y.substring(0,half);
            String d =  y.substring(half);
            String fst = karatsuba(a, c);
            String lst = karatsuba(b, d);
            Long firstarg = Long.parseLong(a)+ Long.parseLong(b);
            Long secondarg = Long.parseLong(c)+ Long.parseLong(d);
            String mdl = karatsuba(Long.toString(firstarg), Long.toString(secondarg));
            Long gauss = Long.parseLong(mdl) - Long.parseLong(fst) - Long.parseLong(lst);
            Long res = ((long)Math.pow(10, n)* Long.parseLong(fst) + Long.parseLong(lst) + (long)Math.pow(10, half) * gauss);
            return Long.toString(res);
        }
        if(n ==1 || m ==1){
            long res = Long.parseLong(x) * Long.parseLong(y);
            return Long.toString(res);
        }
        return "Error !";

    }
   
}
```

Comment: If you need to represent integers bigger than a `long`, use `BigInteger`.

Comment: But if you are doing this for practical reasons ... be aware that `BigInteger` already uses karabatsu, etcetera under the hood.

Comment: Have a look at the lengths of "1000", "10", "00", and `Long.toString(Long.parseLong("00")`. Check the logic of first checking `n > 1` (instead of `0 < half`?!) and only then looking at `m`.

Comment: (While your use of `long` arithmetic is doomed for a product of `two 64 digit [numbers]`, you can implement addition&subtraction for `String`s.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`java.math.BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html). Here's an example multiplying `Long.MAX_VALUE` with `Long.MAX_VALUE`, also showing the output:

```
BigInteger maxLong = BigInteger.valueOf(Long.MAX_VALUE);
BigInteger result = maxLong.multiply(maxLong);
System.out.println(result);

85070591730234615847396907784232501249
```